# Websocket with nginx proxy

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I'm having issues with getting the websocket connected properly with nginx proxy. If I add the port to the use effect it does connect properly.

Here's the react side.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('web socket')
    const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.hostname}/websocket`);
    socket.onopen = () => socket.send('Connected to React')
    setSocketIo(socket)
}, [])
```

Here is the nginx config snippet

```
location /websocket/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

This is error I get in the console.
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/websocket' failed:`

Error from nginx logs
`2022/04/13 13:23:42 [error] 16848#8212: *1499 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0ac97J HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0ac97J", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/guac"`

Is it automatically adding the socket.io to the end of hostname?

Comment: what kind of "issues with getting the websocket connected properly" you have? Do you have any errors in your browser console or nginx server logs?

Comment: This is error I get in the console.
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/websocket' failed: `

Error from nginx logs
`2022/04/13 13:23:42 [error] 16848#8212: *1499 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0ac97J HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0ac97J", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/guac"`

Comment: okay, what actually listens `http://localhost:8000`?

Comment: Its a fastapi server with websocket. It works if I go directly to it with port 8000 from the react app.

Comment: according to nginx logs, your fastapi websocket server refusing connections from nginx

Comment: It's actually not hitting the fastapi websocket at all. It's routing to the default 3000 port to react because its not seeing the /websocket instead nginx is seeing /socket.io I'm not sure if it's automatically adding it to the end.

Comment: `GET /socket.io/...` in your `error.log`, check your code (request side)

Comment: Theres nothing in my code that uses /socket.io/. It automatically puts it at the end of the URL. Is that what WebSocket suppose to do?

Comment: check your source code than, also, what is your `window.location.hostname` value?

Comment: Yep value is localhost. New thing I tried is changing it to /ws and it didnt add the /socket.io but now its giving me a 404 on nginx.
`127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2022:14:50:55 -0700] "GET /ws HTTP/1.1" 404 141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: sure, because your location named `location /websocket/`,  not `/ws/`

Comment: I've also updated the backend fastAPI, nginx and wherever relevant to /ws. I'm using nginx 1.2 instead of 1.3 that could be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I use django-channels, and this is my working nginx settings, Hope this helps you. By the way, I'm still not using this in production but this works in development. You can configure to use WebSocket with WSS and that's all.

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server localhost:8000;
    # here you connect your channel ip:port
}


server {
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
        location /static/ {
        }
        location /media {
        }
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/yourGunicorn.sock;
            # This is for Nginx connection to gunicorn
        }

        location /ws/ {
            try_files $uri @proxy_for_websocket;
            # websocket connection comes with ws
        }
        location @proxy_for_websocket {
            proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        # Your certificate detail here
}
```

from javascript, you are trying to connect with

```
 const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.hostname}/websocket`);
```

**ws** protocol and in your nginx you are writing

```
location /websocket/ {
     ---
     ---
    }
```

which is totally wrong. This should be -

```
location /ws/ {
     ---
     ---
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! this was helpful. I actually found the issue was an unsupported version of uvicorn. Instead of `uvicorn` it required `uvicorn[standard]`

Comment: I use Daphne for my Django :)